# how to replace strings with .env (dotenv-flow) with svelte-kit?

Tags: sveltekit

Inside `svelte.config.js` I have this:

```
    preprocess: autoPreprocess({
        replace: [
            ['API_ENDPOINT', JSON.stringify(process.env.API_ENDPOINT)]
        ]
    }),
```

It should replace the string "API_ENDPOINT" but it isn't.

Here is how I'm using it:

```
async function api(url: string, body = {}, opts = {}) {
    const endpoint = 'API_ENDPOINT';
    console.log(endpoint);
    const res = await fetch(endpoint + url, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(body)
    });

    if (!res.ok) {
        const err = await res.json();
        throw (err || res.statusText);
    }

    return opts.raw ? await res.text() : await res.json();
}

export default api;
```

All i get is `http://localhost:3000/API_ENDPOINT/subscriptions`

Answer (score 3):

in your `svelte.config.js` file, instead of

```js
autoPreprocess({
  replace: [['process.env.NODE_ENV', JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV)]],
});
```

use

```js
import sveltePreprocess from 'svelte-preprocess'
sveltePreprocess({
  replace: [['process.env.NODE_ENV', JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV)]],
});
```

It seems to me that `autoPreprocess` was deprecated but the `README` docs were not correctly updated.

You also may want to consider doing one of the following:

###### use `process.env.API_ENDPOINT` directly

```js
const endpoint = process.env.API_ENDPOINT;
```

###### create a separate javascript function to handle environment variables

something like this

***envVars.js***

```js
import dotenv from 'dotenv-flow';
import path from 'path';

dotenv.config({
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, `path-to-your-(.env)-file`),
});

export const getEnvVar = (key) => process.env[key];
```

and use it like this:

```js
import { getEnvVar } from 'path-to-envVars'
const endpoint = getEnvVar('API_ENDPOINT');
```

###### if you're already using [Vite](https://vitejs.dev/) as your build tool

Add the variables in a `.env` file like so:

```
VITE_YOUR_ENV_VAR_GOES_HERE=bar
```

in your case:

```
VITE_API_ENDPOINT=your_value
```

then import them in a separate javascript or typescript file

***envVars.js***

```js
export const envVars = {
  API_ENDPOINT: import.meta.env.VITE_API_ENDPOINT
};
```

and then import envVars and use it as so:

```js
import { envVars } from 'path-to-envVars.js'
```

and now you can read your environment variable like this:

`envVars.myVariable`
or, in your case
`const endpoint = envVars.API_ENDPOINT`

Comment: I get this error: `500

process is not defined

config@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/dotenv-flow.js?v=d34d57c4:178:9
@http://localhost:3000/src/env.ts:2:10
`

Comment: `export const getEnvVar = (key) => process.env[key];`  it can't find `process`